# A question about completing sentence

Tags: british-english

> Those who favor the new law say that the present law does not set spending limits on lobbyists' gifts to politicians, nor ______ statewide funds.
>
> 1. it limits
> 2. limits it
> 3. does it limit
> 4. does it

I don't know which answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 3. "does it limit"

Comment: can you explain?